# C# SerialPort DataReceived fails to Trigger after random time

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, serial-port

I'm using Visual Studio C# WPF `SerialPort` class to communicate with an microcontroller using USB Cable and driver.

I want to read input from COM port continuously.

This is my current implementation:

```
public SerialConnectionHandler()
{
        port = new SerialPort("COM3");
        port.BaudRate = 9600;
        port.Parity = Parity.None;
        port.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        port.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

        port.Open();
}

private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    String indata = port.ReadLine();
    Debug.WriteLine(indata);

    processInput(inputData);

    if (port.IsOpen) Debug.WriteLine("--Port is Open--");
}
```

After an unspecified time my output console reports at least 5 thread ends with code 0. This sometimes takes seconds, minutes or even longer.

I could not reproduce the problem.

Port Settings Match.

```
Datareceived called
--Port is Open--
Datareceived called
--Port is Open--
Datareceived called
--Port is Open--
Der Thread 0xbb4 hat mit Code 0 (0x0) geendet.
Datareceived called
--Port is Open--
Datareceived called
--Port is Open--
Datareceived called
--Port is Open--
Datareceived called
--Port is Open--
Datareceived called
--Port is Open--
Datareceived called
```

Thread Ends occur randomly, but at one point, a lot of Thread End reports occur. The event won't be triggered from now on anymore.

The port is reported to be opened just before this happens.

```
--Port is Open--
Datareceived called
--Port is Open--
Datareceived called
--Port is Open--
Der Thread 0x3bc hat mit Code 0 (0x0) geendet.
Der Thread 0x2f54 hat mit Code 0 (0x0) geendet.
Der Thread 0x2ea0 hat mit Code 0 (0x0) geendet.
Der Thread 0x1a6c hat mit Code 0 (0x0) geendet.
Der Thread 0x308 hat mit Code 0 (0x0) geendet.
Der Thread 0x2b0c hat mit Code 0 (0x0) geendet.
Der Thread 0x7fc hat mit Code 0 (0x0) geendet.
```

Comment: I can't see where your handler fails to be triggered. There are a bunch of matching pairs of "called" and "open" messages on the output, which seems to be the desired behavior. - Which threads are those that unexpectedly end? Are those "your" threads, or internal threads of some library?

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily make a connection to the thread exit messages. That's pretty normal. Are you keeping a reference to your `SerialConnectionHandler` somewhere to keep it from being garbage collected?

Comment: It works as desired right after start. But soon fails and stops. The thread is, as i believe automatically created upon event creation or event triggering. Why would it be garbage collected? How to keep it from being garbage collected?

Comment: My point on the thread messages is that a .NET program will generate a lot of 'thread exited' messages for a lot of reasons. The ones your seeing may have nothing to do with your problem. In fact, they probably don't. And  yes, a threadpool thread is *used* (not to be confused with being *created*) when the DataReceived event is called.

Comment: As for the possibility of garbage collection, basically you need to save your `SerialConnectionHandler` *somewhere* or the GC will think it is free to clean it up. Hard to say for sure without seeing the context, but a static member in the class that creates it would probably be the best bet. That way, the reference to your `SerialConnectionHandler` is saved and the GC knows that it is still in use. Otherwise, the GC may come along at any random time and decide to clean it up.

Answer (score 1):

So I noticed I had the same problem. On one project `DataReceived` works perfect, as expected, but on another - this problem.

As it turns out, Glorin is right. The `The thread 0xc28 has exited with code 0` I am seeing after few seconds of running my app, is because I was keeping all this code in a seperate class `USBCommunicationManager`, called from my window class (I'm using WPF) like this:

```
new USBCommunicationManager(this);
```

I was simply initializing it, not assigning it to any variable, that's why garbage collector later picked it up and ended the serial read thread.
Just changing it like this, solved the problem:

```
USBCommunicationManager usbCommunicationManager;
..
..
usbCommunicationManager = new USBCommunicationManager(this);
```